# How to execute two commands in Powershell after using Where {(...)}

Tags: powershell, command, where-clause

How can I run both 'rename' command and 'hidden' command after I filtered files using Where condition. Each command runs well on its own when placed first, but the second one is neglected.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force | Where {(
    $_.Extension -ne ".mp3" -and
    $_.Extension -ne ".wmv" )} |
Set-ItemProperty -Name Attributes -Value "Hidden" -WhatIf |
Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace $_.Extension, -join($_.Extension, ".notmusic")} - 
WhatIf
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For-Each:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force | Where {( $_.Extension -ne ".mp3" -and  $_.Extension -ne ".wmv" )} | ForEach-Object {
    $_ | Set-ItemProperty -Name Attributes -Value "Hidden" -WhatIf
    $_ | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace $_.Extension, -join($_.Extension, ".notmusic")} -WhatIf
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this required fewer changes to the script and worked as I intended.

Answer (score 0):

I use [ForEach-Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Core/ForEach-Object?view=powershell-7)

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force | Where {(    $_.Extension -ne ".mp3" -and    $_.Extension -ne ".wmv" )} | ForEach-Object { 
Set-ItemProperty -Name Attributes -Value "Hidden" -Path $_.FullName -WhatIf
Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName "$($_.Name).notmusic" -WhatIf
}
```

I add in [Set-ItemProperty](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Set-ItemProperty?view=powershell-7) `-Path`

```
Set-ItemProperty -Name Attributes -Value "Hidden" -Path $_.FullName -WhatIf
```

i change [Rename-Item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Management/Rename-Item?view=powershell-7) `-Path`  and `-NewName`

```
Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName "$($_.Name).notmusic"
```

Comment: Note. The `%` is an alias for `ForEach-Object`. Also note, that in scripts, aliases should not be used.

Comment: @marsze i changed

Answer (score 0):

I see the first couple stanzas grab files in your directory that are not mp3 or wmv files.

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force | Where {($_.Extension -ne ".mp3" -and $_.Extension -ne ".wmv")}
```

That part is good.  But since you're taking two actions on each file, you should then pipe to a ForEach-Object in the form of

```
... | ForEach-Object {
     # do something
     # do something else
}
```

And since you're not piping directly into the Set-ItemProperty cmdlet, you'll pass it the path of the filename as such:

```
Set-ItemProperty -Path $_.FullName -Name Attributes -Value "Hidden"
```

Then we get to your rename command.  Looks like you want the name to be filename.notmusic.  Again, we'll need to pass the file path to the cmdlet.  Also note how using subexpressions is a clean/nice way of defining the new name

```
Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName "$($_.BaseName).notmusic"
```

Ok so put it all together and we have:

```
Get-ChildItem -Recurse -Force | Where-Object {($_.Extension -ne ".mp3" -and $_.Extension -ne ".wmv")} | ForEach-Object {
    Set-ItemProperty -Path $_.FullName -Name Attributes -Value "Hidden" -WhatIf 
    Rename-Item -Path $_.FullName -NewName "$($_.BaseName).notmusic" -WhatIf
}
```